# RF24L01+ radio module not working without a finger on it

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, rf, debugging

I am having trouble with my RF24 chips, the setup:

two arduino nanos are each connected to a RF24 chips one is connected to a joystick for test data input, the other has four LEDs (in place of an H-bridge for testing) on four pwm pins for output.

- joy pins A0, A1, A2
- PWM pins 5,6, 9,10
- RF24 7,8 + SPI

The sender will not work unless i touch the back of the pins, I narrowed it down to the MOSI pin, by touching each with a metal probe.

I tried adding a small cap to the RF24 power input, I tried adding more capacitance, i tried adding alot more capacitance.

I tried a capacitor from MOSI to ground.

I tried twisting ground wires around the MOSI and MISO wires connecting the NANO and the RF24.

I tried a large 10M pulldown on MOSI.

I tried changing power levels.

I tried changing the channel.

I tried lowering the data rate.

I tried soldering new boards, they either don't work at all or require a finger to transmit.

I tried switching RF24 boards, tried swapping ones from a different batch/manufacture.

I tried moving the boards further apart; no luck.

It functioned properly on one occasion, and everything seemed to work without a hitch for then, but hasn't worked without a finger since, and sometimes not at all.

One last clue: one time it was working, i could control the lights with the joystick, but the serial monitor always said 'FAILED' even though it was clearly working.

Here is the arudino code i was using.
Sending Code:

```
#include <RF24Network.h>
#include "RF24.h"
#include <SPI.h>

/* Hardware configuration: Set up nRF24L01 radio on SPI bus plus pins 7 & 8 */
RF24 radio(7,8);
/**********************************************************/
RF24Network network(radio);      // Network uses that radio
const uint16_t this_send_node = 00;    // Address of our node in Octal format ( 04,031, etc)
const uint16_t other_node = 01;   // Address of the other node in Octal format

struct pair
{
  int x;
  int y;
};

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
  pinMode(A1, INPUT);
  pinMode(A2, INPUT);

  SPI.begin();
  radio.begin();
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_LOW);
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);
  network.begin(/*channel*/ 102, /*node address*/ this_send_node);
}

void loop()
{
  network.update();

  RF24NetworkHeader header(/*to node*/ other_node);
  pair p;
  p.x = analogRead(0);
  p.y = analogRead(1);
  int z = analogRead(2);

  bool ok = network.write(header,&p,sizeof(pair));
  if (!ok)
    Serial.println("failed.");
  else
  {
    Serial.print(p.x);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(p.y);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.println(z);
  }

  delay(10);
}
```

Receiving code:

```
   #include <RF24Network.h>
#include "RF24.h"
#include <SPI.h>

/* Hardware configuration: Set up nRF24L01 radio on SPI bus plus pins 7 & 8 */
RF24 radio(7,8);
RF24Network network(radio);      // Network uses that radio
const uint16_t this_recv_node = 01;    // Address of our node in Octal format ( 04,031, etc)
const uint16_t other_node = 00;   // Address of the other node in Octal format

struct pair
{
  int x;
  int y;
};

int a1 = 5;
int a2 = 6;
int b1 = 9;
int b2 = 10;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(a1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(a2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(b1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(b2, OUTPUT);

  analogWrite(a1, 0);
  analogWrite(a2, 0);
  analogWrite(b1, 0);
  analogWrite(b2, 0);

  SPI.begin();
  radio.begin();
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_LOW);
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);
  network.begin(/*channel*/ 102, /*node address*/ this_recv_node);
  Serial.println("SETUP COMPLETE");
}

void setMotor(int pa1, int pa2, int pb1, int pb2)
{
  analogWrite(a1, pa1);
  analogWrite(a2, pa2);
  analogWrite(b1, pb1);
  analogWrite(b2, pb2);
}

unsigned long last = millis();

void loop() 
{
  pair p;
  network.update();

  while ( network.available() )
  {
    RF24NetworkHeader header; 
    network.read(header, &p, sizeof(pair));
    last = millis();
  }

  int x = p.x - 512;
  int y = p.y - 512;
  int a1=0;
  int b1=0;
  int a2=0;
  int b2=0;

  x /= 2;
  y /= 2;

  int xx = x+y;
  int yy = x-y;

  if (xx >= 0)
    a1 = xx;
  else
    a2 = -xx;

  if (yy >= 0)
    b1 = yy;
  else
    b2 = -yy;

  a1 = constrain(a1,0,255);
  a2 = constrain(a2,0,255);
  b1 = constrain(b1,0,255);
  b2 = constrain(b2,0,255);

  setMotor(a1,a2,b1,b2);

  Serial.print(a1);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(a2);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(b1);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(b2);
  Serial.println(" ");

  // don't run away if the RC cuts
  if(millis() - last  > 500) // no rx for 500 ms 
  {
    setMotor(0,0,0,0); // turn off the motor
    Serial.println("HALTING!!!");
  }
}
```

Comment: A schematic of what exactly you have wired up would be useful.

Comment: Did you also try smaller value pulldowns/pullups? 10M seems quite high.

Comment: @RichardtheSpacecat yes i tried smaller values as well, but the large value was based on a suggestion i found in a forum.

Comment: Your pressed finger tip is about 1nF ballpark and 50k. But it sounds like CM noise interfering with unbalanced lines which means you need to lower the MOSI impedance and maybe use a CM shield at one end only. or else glue your finger to the board.....